# Shiny sliderInput Number Formatting Issue (wrong format)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `sliderInput` in a shiny app with small numbers, which are not shown correctly (see screenshot below).

[image]

Obviously the current selectin should be rendered as 0.512,23 and not as 0.51,234 (same for the first number and all axis-ticks). Is this a bug in shiny or did I do something wrong?

How can I fix the numbering format? Also, as I have many sliderInputs, I would prefer an option that doesn't require changing every input.

To reproduce the error I use this code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  sliderInput("val", "Some Value", min = 1e-5, max = 1, step = 1e-5, value = 0.51234),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText(sprintf("val is %f", input$val))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have these specs:

```
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS: /usr/lib/openblas-base/libblas.so.3
#> LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.18.so
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_3.4.2  backports_1.1.0 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.2  
#>  [5] tools_3.4.2     htmltools_0.3.6 yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.12   
#>  [9] stringi_1.1.5   rmarkdown_1.6   knitr_1.17      stringr_1.2.0  
#> [13] digest_0.6.12   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It seems an [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/31) with `shiny`

Previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636335/formatting-number-output-of-sliderinput-in-shiny) suggested to use `sep=""`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  sliderInput("val", "Some Value", min = 1e-5, max = 1, step = 1e-5, value = 0.51234, sep =''),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderText(sprintf("val is %f", input$val))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: that makes it look better! But the separators are gone... Any idea how to avoid that?
`format` seems to be the right thing, but its deprecated.