# Setting slider in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to set slider in Shiny. Below you can see my code :

```
 column(2,
         h4("Baseline-t0"),
         sliderInput("simulationSlider1", "Base Year",
         min = 2022, max = 2023, step = 1, value = 2022, width = "100%", round = 0),
                           ),
```

This code produce slider as is shown in the figure below :

[image]

Instead of integer numbers, on this slider I can see figure such as 2,022 and 2,023.Can anybody help me how I can set slider to show me integer number such as 2022 and 2023 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting number output of sliderInput in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636335/formatting-number-output-of-sliderinput-in-shiny)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `sep` in the `sliderInput`, which is  `sep = ","` as default. A fully reproducible example is below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("simulationSlider1", "Base Year",
              min = 2022, max = 2023, step = 1, 
              value = 2022, width = "100%", 
              round = 0, sep = ""),
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$simulationSlider1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]